# Traer un ManyToManyField en un listado de registros en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo en Django:

class Modelo:
...

```
 field_many = models.ManyToManyField(Many, blank=True)
```

Hago una consulta al modelo

```
     modelo=Modelo.objects.filter(id__in=ids).values('value1','value2'...).order_by(order)
```

Ahora intento traer los field_many que tiene cada registro y meterlos en un array, pero esto es un bucle for y ocupa mucha memoria en el servidor.

```
  for model in modelo:
        c = Modelo.objects.prefetch_related('field_many').get(id=model['id'])
        many_data = []
        for field_many in c.field_many.all():
            many_data.append(field_many.name)
            
        charge['many_names'] = many_data
```

¿Tienen alguna idea de como poder hacerlo sin que afecte al rendimiento con un bucle for?

Comment: ¿Tienes un error de memoria en tu aplicación? O la pregunta es si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

En tu código no queda muy claro qué resultado necesitas o para qué vas a usarlo, si lo puedes aclarar, mejor.

Si quieres obtener todas las instancias del modelo `Many` vinculadas a las instancias del modelo `Modelo` con `id` contenido en `ids`, puedes dejar que el ORM haga su magia y la base de datos se encargue de eso. Puedes usar la capacidad que tiene Django de [seguir las relaciones inversas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) de como se han declarado (en lugar de `Modelo` a `Many`, de `Many` a `Modelo`):

```
manies = Many.objects.filter(modelo__id__in=ids)
```

Si lo que quieres es una lista (un array en Python) con los nombres de esas instancias de `Many`, Django ya nos ofrece como hacerlo de una en la clase `QuerySet`, que es la que nos devuelve normalmente el resultado de una consulta en este framework. Para use usaremos el [método `values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
many_names = Many.objects.filter(modelo__id__in=ids).values_list("name", flat=True)
```

`flat=True` es un caso especial cuando sólo pasamos un único nombre de campo a `values_list()`. En lugar de devolver una lista de tuplas de los valores de los campos pasados como parámetro a este método, devuelva una lista de los valores de ese único campo que se ha pasado como parámetro.

Espero haber entendido bien tu duda y haberla resuelto.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use la función de agregación `array_agg` o similar para su respectiva base de datos. Esta función acepta un conjunto de valores y devuelve un array como resultado de la evaluación del conjunto de entrada (como los de una columna dentro de un conjunto de una o más filas).

En el caso de postgres dispone de la función de agregación [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) que simplifica la solución:

```
Modelo.objects.annotate(many_data=ArrayAgg('field_many__name'))
```

Comment: Esa función solo funcionaría con PostgresSQL